# Base SDK 6.1 doesnt show iOS 8 simulators in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My app currently has a Base SDK of 6.1

Ive put iPhoneOS6.1.sdk into:
Xcode> Developer> Platforms> iPhoneOS.platform> Developer> SDKs>

And it allows me to build with the base SDK set to iOS6.1

But unless if I have the Base SDK set to 8.0, it doesnt show me any of the simulators running iOS 7.0, 7.1 or 8.0

Does anyone have a way of getting it to show me all the simulators even though my Base SDK is 6.1?

Comment: Why do this? Update your app to use a Base SDK of 8.0. You had the last 3 months to update and test your app for iOS 8. Otherwise you can use Xcode 5 to test your 6.1 Bask SDK app on a development device running iOS 8.

Comment: Using Xcode 5 is fine for the moment but usually apple turn of the ability to upload with an old version of xcode after a certain amount of time, we will not be updating our app to use the new ios7 style (and ios 7 base sdk) until next year for certain reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the other available iOS simulators (7.1 , 7.0 and 6). Worked for me

Comment: I tried this but they only show when the base sdk is set to 8.0 oddly enough. Did you download them through xcode or some website? and can you confirm your using xcode 6.0.1 now?

Comment: Ok as soon as i put the 6.1 simulator into the xcode package contents, all simulators were showing even though my base SDK was 6.1 Solved! :D

Comment: Bad advice.  Please, please, please don't do this!

Answer (score 11):

In Xcode 6.1 you can add simulators manually. To do so go to Window -> Devices and press the + symbol left at the bottom.

[image]

Then you can choose a combination of device type and iOS version to create.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Windows` -> `Devices` and press the plus in the bottom corner and add the simulators that you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Do not copy the older SDKs into newer Xcode.  That is unsupported and very likely to lead to problems.

You should be using the latest SDK and setting the deployment target to the oldest OS you want to support.  I believe most developers right now are using the 8.1 SDK (or just set it to latest) with a deployment target of either 6.1 or 7.1.